# If a couple keeps having kids until they have a girl, what's the expected number of kids?

Tags: probability

The problem is as follows:

*A couple wants to have a baby girl. They decide to have children until they have a girl, but they will give up if they have 4 consecutive boys. What is the expected number of boys and the expected number of girls in their family?*

We were already asked a similar problem, and I attempted to solve this in the same way that I solved that one. Let "expected children" be represented by the variable ec.

$\begin{equation}
ec = (1/2)*1 + (1/2)*(ec + 1)
\end{equation}$

I figured this would be accounting for the initial chance that the child would be a girl, (1/2), multiplied by all of the other possibilities from there on out that the child would be a girl.

When you solve for ec, it equals 2. Therefore, if the expected number of children is 2, and if the couple would have stopped having children if the first were a girl, and would have continued if the first and second were both boys, then the first child must have been a boy and the second a girl. So the answer would be 1 boy, and 1 girl.

My problem, is that I realized I didn't factor the information about the couple not having any more children after 4 consecutive boys anywhere into my equation, and I'm really not sure how to include that mathematically.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. (I have a feeling that my answer is right but that I used the wrong equation to get it).

Comment: You basically only have 5 possibilities: $BBBB$, $BBBG$, $BBG$, $BG$, and $G$. What is the probability of each of them?

Comment: @Clement C. I mean, that would be (1/2)^4, (1/2)^4, (1/2)^3, (1/2)^2, and (1/2), yeah? But how do I turn that into expected number of children?

Comment: Ex[X] = Sum_x X*P(X)

Comment: @Tweej Thank you for taking the time to respond. We just started doing this stuff in class and haven't covered the notation at all. Would you possibly be willing to explain that a little further to me? I looked up expected value and it said the sum of each value times its probability. So I did 1*1/2 + 2(1/2)^2 + 3(1/2)^3 + 2(4(1/2)^4) and it gave me 1.875. But you can't have 1.875 kids obviously. The value I was plugging into the equation there was just the number of kids for each situation, but I don't know if that's right.

Comment: The expected number of kids can certainly be 1.875. As a simpler example, suppose half the families had one kid and half had two, the expected number of kids would be 1.5.

Comment: That's exactly it. The expected value of a variable is the probability of that variable * the value of it. In this case, what you have found is the expected number of kids if the rules were: You stop after having a daughter or once you have 4 kids. But what if we included 5 kids? Then we would add a factor 5*(1/2)^5. Then 6? 6*(1/2)^6. You notice there's a pattern? We can write that the expected value = sum_n n*(1/2)^n as n-> inf.

Comment: You can statistically have $1.875$ children, definitively, just imagine $8$ couples with a total of $15$ children. Now reverse the reasoning, if I told you that only 7 out of 8 will have a second child an none the third, what is the expected number of children per couple?

Comment: @Tweej Thanks guys! Well so now my final question is, if I have to say how many of the expected kids are boys and how many are girls, how do I do that?